# how can i make the threads run in sequential order ? (OpenMP)

Tags: c, linux, openmp

Already understood how parallel programming working , 
but is there a way that i can print the sequential order of the threads?

```
#include <omp.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n",
            omp_get_thread_num());
    }

}
```

my output :

```
Hello World... from thread = 2
Hello World... from thread = 3
Hello World... from thread = 0
Hello World... from thread = 1
```

goal output:

```
Hello World... from thread = 0
Hello World... from thread = 1
Hello World... from thread = 2
Hello World... from thread = 3
```

Comment: Threads run independently in parallel, so their order is not specified unless you introduce synchronisation.

Comment: If you have a parallel for loop, you can use the `ordered` clause, but that kind of defeats the point of using openmp.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the `ordered` keyword to get the output in order. In practice you want to have a lot of independent computations and then only print (or copy or whatever) the result in order.

Not an expert on this but here is how I do it (works on gcc and msvc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int blah(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // this may or may not be necessary..
    omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());

    int i;
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for ordered schedule(static, 1)
    for(i = 0; i < omp_get_num_threads(); i++)
    {
        // This is where the heavy computations go
#pragma omp ordered
        {
            // synchronized and in order; keep this short
            printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Don't understand why your question got down voted. Having the result in order is a valid use case imho.